# How to use local docker image as base in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-build, buildx

I am a complete beginner to Docker and I need some help with this.

I have a custom docker image, I want to build it and push it to the Docker hub. For that I have a Dockerfile which has the below line.

FROM customimage:tag

Now when I try to build it for multiple platform using docker buildx build and push it to my Docker hub, It is trying to get the image from the docker hub instead of using the image present locally.

How to solve this issue.

For better understanding I am attaching output to docker images command and the contents of my Dockerfile here.

```
(base) pranavkaushikdhara@Pranavs-MacBook-Air GitHubData_push % docker images
 REPOSITORY                    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
 dharapranavkaushik7/elastic   latest    e5f766350178   2 seconds ago   767MB
 elasticsearch                 8.11.3    23562195abe6   5 weeks ago     767MB
```

Dockerfile:
FROM dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest

Here is the output of the build command

```
(base) pranavkaushikdhara@Pranavs-MacBook-Air GitHubData_push % docker buildx build - 
-platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest --push .

 [+] Building 29.8s (5/5) FINISHED                                           docker-container:serene_kilby                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                                   
  => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                                    
  => => creating container buildx_buildkit_serene_kilby0                                                                                                                                
  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                  
  => => transferring dockerfile: 76B                                                                                                                                                    
  => ERROR [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for 
  docker.io/dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest                                                                                        
  => CANCELED [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for 
  docker.io/dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest                                                                                     
  => [auth] dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                             
  ------
   > [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for 
  docker.io/dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest:
  ------
  Dockerfile:1
  --------------------
   1 | >>> FROM dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest
  --------------------
  ERROR: failed to solve: dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest: 
  docker.io/dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest: not found
```

Comment: Why your target `-t` is the same as `FROM`? Can you add output from `docker image inspect dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest -f "{{.RepoTags}} {{.Architecture}}"` When you build without `platform` argument is it working?

Comment: @zori, This is the output 
[dharapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest] arm64

Even without the platform argument,the command doesn't work.Both the target and FROM are same because,I want this tag to have the multi-platform image.

Comment: Try run `docker buildx build -t test --push .` target and source image should never have the same name, it just doesn't make sense if you want for different platform you need build image from scratch. The error is because you don't have `dharapranavkaushik7/elastic` for ARM(you have only amd64) and it's trying to pull it from docker.io and it's failing as it doesn't exist

Comment: Or other question how did you built first `harapranavkaushik7/elastic:latest`?